# Jquery change checkbox checked / uncheked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to uncheck / check the below checkbox using jquery.

Please tell how to change the below checked attribute to unchecked attribute using jquery.

```
<input name="op1" type="checkbox" checked  id="chkEmailNotification" />
```

Comment: Try to spend some time for searching before posting such kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#chkEmailNotification").prop('checked',true); //to Check
$("#chkEmailNotification").prop('checked',false); //to Uncheck
```